# failed to connect to mysql at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root(azure)

Tags: mysql, azure, authentication

'failed to connect to mysqlat 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root' error appears

I went into Control Panel, System, Environment Variables, Path, and put the path C:\Program Files\MySQL; where my mysql was installed.

However, the error still appears.
:(

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: can you share error which you are getting?

Comment: If you go in and get what mysql Connections made,
'could not axquire management access for administration'

'runtimeerror: unable to execute command chcp.
please make sure that the c:\'could not axquire management access for administration'
This error is coming out.

Then click settings to enter and click test connection.

'failed to connect to mysql at 127.0.0.1:3306 with user root'

'unable to connect to localhost'

This is all I know.